# Como definir o componente a ser renderizado no Link do React-Router-Dom?

Tags: react, react-router-dom

Segundo a [documentação](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link/component-reactcomponent), é possível renderizar um elemento customizado no Link do React-Router-Dom:

> If you would like utilize your own navigation component, you can
> simply do so by passing it through the component prop.

Tentei renderizar um web component no lugar do link, porém o estilo do meu web component não está sendo carregado no lugar do Link, está carregando apenas uma `<a>`:

```
<Link
    to={ROUTE.REGISTRY}
    component={() =>
      (<my-webcomponent-link />
      )}
>
    Registrar
</Link>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para renderizar um componente customizado usando o Link do React-router-dom, basta passar seu componente como um "filho" dele:

```
<Link
    to="url-que-quer-acessar"
    style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}
>
    <SeuComponente> Registrar </SeuComponente>
</Link>
```

Colocando `style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}` faz com que a estilização da tag  não seja mais aplicada.

Caso a mensagem "registrar" deva ser inserida dentro do seu componente, em algum lugar especifico, você pode passar ela como sendo "filha" do seu componente, e acessá-la por `props.children()`.

Exemplo -> Digamos que SeuComponente é apenas uma div com o texto:

```
export default function SeuComponente(props) {
    // props.children é uma propriedade que o react passa automaticamente
    // tudo que você insere dentro do seu componente quando chama ele
    // no nosso caso, foi o texto "Registrar"
    return (<div>{props.children}</div>);
}
```

Comment: O estilo do <a> do Link ainda é aplicado =[

Comment: Nesse caso, será necessário adicionar: `style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}` no componente Link, atualizei a resposta para ver exatamente onde colocar